# git branch on another server

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

I am working with a customer who provided git branch access to get the latest src code. I've to continue working with that src code.
But my company won't allow me to commit the src code directly to their branch. And so, my company provided with our own repository account to commit the additions/modifications/deletions etc.
I would like to know if we can branch my customer's src code into our repository so that at the end of the project I can merge with customer's code easily. May be just by a pull request to customer's server. 
Is my understanding correct or is there any other better alternative to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you are facing the following situation:

`remote repository of the customer, lets call it A`

`your repository of your company, lets call it B`

You pulled from A

`git pull A branchName`

And you want to put your changes to the `B`-repository:

`git remote add B /url/to/B/repo.git`

Than you can easily push to B

`git push B yourChangesToBranchName`

Now you are able to pull in changes from A and push them to B without any interfering problems. Hope this is what you want.

Comment: At the end, can I send a pull request to "A"? Also can I work on local src code on my machine and pull it to B. Will it cause any problem with merging with A?

Comment: It's kind of hard to follow your requirements. So lets break your questions down: 1. Yes you can send a pull request to A, [further reading](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull). 2. If you work on your local machine and you have added the new remote for B, you can push and pull to/from this repository as you like. 3. Of course it is possible that any merging problems occur. That depends on your development and the one on A's side.

Answer (score -1):

`git` is a distributed version control system *by design*.

This means, that a workflow, where you pull changes from one server and push them to another server is very well supported.

However, a single commit in git also includes a reference to the entire history of this commit (by means of the commit-hash).
This means that the repository you pull from and the repository you push to must share the entire history.

In practice this means, that you cannot just use any existing git-repository of your company, but need to create a new one (`git init`) on your company's git server.